# jquery event.preventdefault problem

Tags: jquery

My `event.preventdefault` is not working. Actually I want when the user clicks the add button, it will ask to "enter the field first" if all the field are blank.

For this, I use the flag like this to prevent the data saved if all fields are blank as below: (also when i click the button it shows enter the field and after that it will go to ajax function even i applied `event.preventdefault();` I don't know exactly where I am wrong)

Thanks in advance,

**Here is my code:**

```
 <tr>
        <td>
            <button type="button" name="add">     //this is my add button
                Add
            </button>
        </td>
   </tr>
       $("#tabs").tabs();
       $("button").button();
       $("button").click(function(event){
            var flagg=0;
            if( $("#patient_name").val() == "" )
            {
                flagg=1;
            }
            if(flagg == 1)
            {
                alert("enter the patient name!!");
                event.preventDefault();
            }

        form_name = $(this).parents("form").attr('name');
        var params    = $("#" + form_name).serialize();
        params=params.replace(/&/g,'~^~^^');
        table_name = "patient_info";
        button_name = "temp";

        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "ajax1.php",
             data: "params=" + params + "&button_name=" + button_name,
             success: function(msg){
                 //alert(msg);
                if (msg == "true")
                {
                    alert("Patient data sucessfully saved!");
                    window.location.replace("ivf2.php?id=" + $("#id").val());
                }   
                else    
                {
                    //alert("Failed to save, please check and try again!");
                }
        }
        });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

`event.preventDefault` simply stops any other attached event from running (e.g. something in `onclick` or `href`). It doesn't make your own javascript code stop.

Do this:

```
if(flagg == 1)
    {
        alert("enter the patient name!!");
        event.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

At the line `if(flagg == 1)` you are calling the event.preventDefault(), but then you are continuing on with your ajax post.  At that point you want to return via `return;` from your click handler so that it does not continue submitting the form.